Why is my function to call javascript file not working in wordpress plugin?
I'm trying to add a function inside my php file, which is inside an /admin/ folder, to call a specific javascript file, roomzeroadmin.js.
I've tried using:
function roomzero_load_admin_scripts() {
    // Enqueue admin.js for the admin dashboard
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'roomzero-admin-script', // Unique handle
        plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/roomzeroadmin.js', // Path to admin.js
        array('jquery'), // Dependencies (if any)
        '1.0.0', // Version
        true // Load in footer
    );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'roomzero_load_admin_scripts');

but it just doesn't seem to work. I also tried
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','roomzero_js');

function roomzero_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'roomzero-test-js', plugins_url( '/js/roomzero.js', __FILE__ ));
}

but that doesn't work either. Any suggestions on how I can make this work?

define "doesn't work" for us. The script isn't loaded at all into your page? Or it tries to execute but there's a console error? Or it doesn't do what you expected? Or there's a PHP error? or, or, or...what is the actual specific problem you're experiencing? We can't run your code, so the absolute basic debugging / testing is your job, to narrow down the problem to something tangible. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue.

@ADyson The script isn't loaded at all

So you mean that when you load your page, while watching your browser's Network tool, no entry for roomzeroadmin.js ever appears in the Network log? Is that, specifically, what you mean by that statement? Please try to be specific, details can be important. [edit] your question to clarify the scenario - it shouldn't go into the comments, as this isn't a discussion board. Reminder: [ask]

Trying to help troubleshoot a bit.
How are you running the javascript? Via a page-specific snippet, via your functions or via a plugin?
Also, you probably already did that, just double check that since you're working within the /admin/ folder, that you make sure that you're specifically targeting the admin pages and loading your script there.
Also, double check to make sure your filepath actually points to the correct location of roomzeroadmin.js.
If your roomzeroadmin.js file is located at /wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/js/roomzeroadmin.js, plugin_dir_url(FILE) will give the correct base URL, so you should be fine there. However, double-check the structure.
Make sure the array('jquery') dependency is correct. Do you specifically need jquery?
Here if a clean piece of code that you can test with:
function roomzero_load_admin_scripts($hook) {
    // Check if we're on the admin pages (optional: you can specify exact pages by checking the $hook)
    if (is_admin()) {
        // Enqueue the roomzeroadmin.js file
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'roomzero-admin-script', // Unique handle for the script
            plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/roomzeroadmin.js', // Path to the JS file
            array('jquery'), // Dependencies (jQuery is common in the admin area)
            '1.0.0', // Version of your script
            true // Load in the footer (set to false if you want it in the header)
        );
    }
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'roomzero_load_admin_scripts');

Good luck.
